# PostgreSQL UPDATE query string too long?

Tags: postgresql

I have made a query thats getting bigger and bigger with a lot of

```
SET column = CASE WHEN other_table.column LIKE b
             THEN c
FROM other_table
```

Is it possible to give `other_table` an alias, for example `other`, because it's a very long name and I need to copy & paste different tables each time for new tables with the same query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```
SET column = CASE WHEN other.column LIKE b
                  THEN c
             END
FROM other_table AS other
```